# Adding or Updating XML Node PHP?

Tags: php, xml

XML structure:

```
<root>
    <book> 
        <author>Isak Azimov</author>
        <name>End of spirit</name>
       <date>10/05/2018</date>
    </book>
</root>
```

If I have record in my XML file that already exist, PHP script must to update only date of the record not to insert it as a new one. How to make this comparing about the values in nodes author and name with the new values that entered in form?

Comment: Have you tried simplexml or any of the parsers?

Comment: I make it like this: I parse the author and name and deleted if exist and make it new record with the new date